# Telegram / telebot не отправляется фото по ссылке

Tags: python, telebot, img

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('1378893112:AAHcD2zO871zHpQ_hs3tuVzAptRL2AYmtEU')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start, чтобы продолжить и увидить мемы с Просенюк выбери и напиши цифру от 1 до 10.')


@bot.message_handler(command=['meme'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://ibb.co/mRKXwk3');


bot.polling()
```

не отправляется фото с ссылки

Comment: попробуйте назвать функции по-разному

Comment: спасибо за токен. и будьте внимательнее - command**s**